# Finding a ¬ character in linux and Windows

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a c# project that needs to run on both Windows and Linux. The program has to search for a pointer in the file which is the '¬' character. This works fine on Windows but when I try and run the program on linux the ¬ character is replaced by ï¿½ so the program is failing.

How can I get this to work.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: What is the file encoding, and are you specifying it correctly on each platform? What's *creating* the file in each case? My guess is that on Windows it's using CP-1252 and on Linux it's using UTF-8...

Comment: To validate the encoding, open the file on in a binary hex editor and check that you really have the content you expect.

Comment: You may want to reference http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html if you are unsure of encodings character sets and the like.

Comment: In the streamreader I am using Encoding.Default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I i found out that @alfonso was right using the characters hex code but although it still displayed the funny character, I found that I need to change the encoding for the stream to UTF7.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use the character hex code: `'\x00AC'`

Comment: thanks but it didn't work. It works in Windows but in Linux it is still showing the funny character

Comment: Just because that's what is showing doesn't mean its not the same character. One code page to another can render different glyphs.

Comment: I know its not the same one as the program is returning false when it should be returning true once it has found the pointer

Comment: if you are using c# its not finding the pointer it looking at the charter stream coming off the stream reader most likely.  There are binary differences between text files on windows and linux and they can pose another issue. The best way to test is to write a c# program that writes only the charter code '\x00AC' to a file and see if you get the same results then set the encoding to utf7 on both and see if it work the same.